# 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, attributes, return, attributeerror

I would like to return number in views.py but always get the attribute error. I am not want to get something, I just want to return a variable, but it always shows " object has no attribute 'get'". I had tried to change return the number to string and list, but all got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 27, in process_response
    if response.get("X-Frame-Options") is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /scan-port/
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

This is my code in views.py function

```
   number = 3

   return number
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. I had searched online but no solution found!

Comment: Very explicit, a `list` has no attribute `get/method` you should try to print the type by using `type(response)`

Answer (score 0):

A view needs to return a HttpResponse.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('hello')
```

You should also share your whole view instead of just two lines of it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to print(type()) for checking purposes if the variable is really type that you want?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to print the type, the type is <class 'int'>. Actually, I can use the data in any type as long as it could return, but all shows the attribute error

Comment: well if you want to getting type list use
`return [2]`
but list don't have method `.get()`.
here's the list of the method in list: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp)
.
`<variable list>.get(<key>, <default if not present>)` is for dictionary.
Here's the ref for dictionary:
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp)

Comment: usually the view only return with `HttpResponse` in view

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).